# Using Spring AOP uses underneath aspectj?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, aspect

Hy,

Reading a lot about Spring AOP vs AspectJ, I still have some doubts:

1.)When using Spring AOP with classes annotated with @Aspect and using "aop:aspectj-autoproxy" tag , it can be said that we are using just the annotations of aspectj or besides that it is being used AspectJ too for the weaving?

2) Its said that AspectJ has better performance because the weaving is in compilation time, it means that the target class files are physically changed inserting the aspects in them? is it not a bit aggressive?

3)It said that Spring uses proxys for AOP, so, I undertand that when you get a bean from Spring, Spring builds a proxy in memory that has already inserted the aspects in it, right?
So why is it said that when a method from your proxy bean calls other method in the proxy, the last method will not have aspects?

Thanks

Comment: did the post bellow reply to what you where looking, or was there something unclear?

Answer (score 1):

1) using `aspectj-autoproxy` means that `@Aspect`annotations are recognized, but Spring proxies are still being created, see this quote from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html):

> Do not be misled by the name of the  element:
>   using it will result in the creation of Spring AOP proxies. The
>   @AspectJ style of aspect declaration is just being used here, but the
>   AspectJ runtime is not involved.

2) AspectJ supports load time weaving, byte code weaving and compile time weaving. There should no difference in performance, it's just a different point in time to weave the aspect in (compilation, third party jars available, class load time), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837158/combining-spring-and-java-ee) for further details.

It is actually more transparent once it's set up to have the aspects weaved at these moments, with runtime proxies there are problems when a bean calls itself using this.someMethod, the aspects don't get applied because the proxies get bypassed (@Transactional/@Secured does not work, etc.).

3) Have a look at this picture from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html):

[image]

With runtime proxies (non AspectJ), Spring leaves the bean class untouched. What it does is it creates a proxy that either implements the same interface as the bean (JDK proxy), or if the bean implements no interface then it dynamically creates a proxy class with CGLIB (subclass of bean).

But in both cases a proxy is created that delegates the calls to the actual bean instance. So when the bean call t`his.methodB()` from `methodA`, the proxy is bypassed because the call is made directly on the bean and not on the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Spring AOP can be configured with AspectJ-sytle, ie annotations are parsed to build configuration but AspectJ compiler is not used for weaving. Only a subset of AspectJ annotations and poincut definitions can be used with Spring AOP.
2. Maybe, but I don't know any class that has complained. However, is possible that some classes don't allow re-weaving when modified by other bytecode tools.
3. Inner calls are not proxied because they call on `this.method()` (with `this` = the target bean begin proxied)  and not on `proxy.method()` so the proxy has no chances to intercept the call. However, Spring AOP proxies usually notices when a target method return `this` and return itself instead, so calls like `builder.withColor(Color.RED).withHat(Hat.Cowboy)` will work. Note that in Spring AOP there are always **two** classes involved: the proxy and the target.